# Help identifying sealed Lego Bag 4 from 2017 set long red flat pieces, blue flames, green bricks, blue tint windows misc small black parts

Tags: set-identification

Need help to identify which set bag 4 came from?  Have a random bag #4.  No idea which set it goes to.  Bag label is 706R2. Bag year is 2017.  Has green bricks and red pieces, four blue flames, and 7 blue windows like pieces.[image: pic of bag4]

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be the bag for the car wash in [Town Center (60292)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/60292-1/town-center/):

[image: Town Center set photo]

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are amazing.